# powershell email body from file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to read the content of a text file into a string variable with powershell in order to use it to send an email (via smtp).

Using `Get-Content` I have no problem reading the contents of a file into a variable:

```
$body = Get-Content 'C:\somewhere\some-file.html'
```

The problem is

```
Send-MailMessage -To [recipient] -From [sender] -Subject [subject] -Body $body -SmtpServer [ip address]
```

fails with the message

> Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to 'System.String' required by 'Body' parameter. Specified method not supported.

How can I get the file contents into the variable as a `String`? I've tried converting the resulting `Object[]` array to a `String` by piping the `$body` variable with `Convert-String` but with no success.

Edit

To anyone looking for a one-liner, with the help of Mark's answer below here it is:

```
Send-MailMessage -To recipient@domain.com -From sender@domain.com -Subject "Test" -Body (Get-Content 'C:\somewhere\some-file.html' | Out-String) -SmtpServer 123.456.789.012 -BodyAsHtml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$body = Get-Content 'C:\somewhere\some-file.html' | Out-String
```

The problem is probably that `Get-Content` is creating an array of strings and the `-Body` parameter is expecting a single string.

The `Out-String` cmdlet I think would convert it to a single string.

Comment: From PSv3+ you could use the `-raw` prarameter of [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6)