# Publishing output to email and or txt file in powershell

Tags: powershell, file, email, text

I am trying to get the following code to either print to a text file and or print to an email so i can send out a daily update for something but I am having a whale of a time getting it to do either

```
if ( ((Get-Date) - (ls P:\cognosdata\cubes\CheckAnalysis.mdc).LastWriteTime).Day -lt 1) {Write-Output "Check Analysis updated today"}

if ( ((Get-Date) - (ls P:\cognosdata\cubes\coupon tracking.mdc).LastWriteTime).Day -lt 1) {Write-Output "Coupon Tracking updated today"}

if ( ((Get-Date) - (ls P:\cognosdata\cubes\rest summary menu mix.mdc).LastWriteTime).Day -lt 1) {Write-Output "Rest Summary Menu Mix updated today"}

if ( ((Get-Date) - (ls P:\cognosdata\cubes\porchmenumix.mdc).LastWriteTime).Day -lt 1) {Write-Output "Porch menu mix updated today"}

if ( ((Get-Date) - (ls P:\cognosdata\cubes\CashDaypart.mdc).LastWriteTime).Day -lt 1) {Write-Output "Cash Daypart updated today"}
```

when it is formatted like this it runs just fine in powershell but then i cannot get it to print to a file or email, any help would be appreciated thank you

I just want this to print to either an email or txt file that i can then schedule to send out daily

I tried this but no luck

```
$filePath = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\cubereport.txt"

# Check if CheckAnalysis.mdc was updated today
if ((Get-Date) - (Get-Item "P:\cognosdata\cubes\CheckAnalysis.mdc").LastWriteTime)).Day -lt 1 {
    Write-Output "Check Analysis updated today" | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append
} else { $null }
```

same with this

```
Write-Output "Check Analysis updated today" | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append
```

Comment: E.g. [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file)? Or apply [PowerShell redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection#powershell-redirection-operators)?

Comment: out file is what i was trying but could not get it to to work, not very familiar with powershell

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. 
Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve].

Comment: ya no problem i have included now

Comment: Please put those 3 backtick on a line of their own... (I just made the edit)

Comment: Simply put everything in a text file, and the take a look at: [powershell email body from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55238756/powershell-email-body-from-file)

Comment: im havi ng trouble getting it to go to a file as well

Comment: [Powershell: How to show output onscreen and output to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632203/powershell-how-to-show-output-onscreen-and-output-to-file), or  [\[powershell\] how to write output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+how+to+write+output+to+file)

Comment: But maybe you should follow this: [Introduction to PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/introduction-to-powershell/)

Comment: haha wow thanks!